# Dojo aspect before not working on dojo request

Tags: javascript, dojo, aspect

I have a Dojo class that uses `dojo/request` to submit various requests to the server.

I need to use `dojo/aspect` to add a *before* advice to those requests.

The [docs](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/aspect.html) seem relatively easy to understand.

My class declaration looks something like this:

```
'myPackage/MyClass':function(){
    define("myPackage/MyClass", [
        "dojo/request", 
        // etc. etc. 
        "dojo/aspect"
    ], function(request, ..., aspect) {
        return declare("myPackage.MyClass", null, {
            constructor: function(options){
                aspect.before(dojo, "request", 
                    function(url, args){
                        // TODO
                        alert("before advice applied"); 
                    }
                );
            },
            // various functions that use dojo request
        });
    }

);
}
```

My problem is that the before advice is never executed.

I've tried a few variants, such as targeting `this` instead of `dojo`, or targeting `request` directly and its only visible function when inspected, `xhr`.

I even went back to the doc page in desperation and tried targeting `dojo` with method `"xhr"` to see if it couldn't by chance be invoked internally, but nothing ever worked.

Is there maybe something obvious that I've overlooked?

**Edit**

I tried modifying my code so that the before advice was executed targeting `this` and a frequently used function.

Something like: `aspect.before(this, "theFrequentlyUsedFunction",`

That worked just fine right out of the box, which means I can use a cumbersome workaround and add a `before` advice for each of the functions invoking `request`, assuming the time complexity of statements preceding the `request` call in those functions is trivial.

My conclusion so far is that I'm not referencing the right target and function name when applying advice before Dojo `request` calls, but I'm still baffled as per why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case "request" is not a property of "dojo" object. It's just a name of argument passed in function. So you can assign it to any property of any object, even to property of your module. So you was close to solution. Take a look on my example:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    .....
    "dojo/request",
    "dojo/aspect"
], function (
    declare,
    .....
    request,
    aspect
) {

    return declare("Test", [...], {            
        request: request,  
        constructor: function () {
            aspect.before(this, "request", function () {
                console.log("before advice applied");
            });
        }
        ......
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it's quite simple and works, with a (kind of obvious) caveat: you need to refactor calls to `request` to `this.request`, in order for the advice to apply.

Comment: Glad to help. Unfortunately I don't see any other way at the moment to make it work, till `request` exists only as argument in scope of define's factory function...